# JavaScript: Getting evaluated properties of an object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have two objects similar to this:

```
var person = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe'
};

var myObj = {
    fullName: function () {
        return person.fname + ' ' + person.lname; 
    }
};
```

What I need is an object like this – `myObj`, but evaluated:

```
var someObj = {
    fullName: 'John Doe'
};
```

Since `myObj` will be passed to a templating engine, it's required as JSON anyway, so I found a way using `JSON.stringify`:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (typeof value == 'function') {
        return value.call();
    }
    return value;
}

var someObj = JSON.stringify(myObj, replacer);
```

While this works, I feel that it's quite brittle and I would like to do some research on it. Is there a special name for functions like `replacer`, are there any libraries that come with a more mature implementation of `replacer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `fullName` a ["getter" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) using the proper syntax in the object literal.

```js
var person = {
    fname: 'John',
    lname: 'Doe',

    // fullName will be evaluated on property access
    get fullName() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname; 
    }
};


document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(person, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

This is an ECMAScript 5 feature, so it will not be available in old browsers, like IE8 and lower.